# Electron build timing out on CircleCI

Tags: electron, circleci

I am trying to get CircleCI to work with my electron app but I can't understand how to stop the timeout error.

You can look at the app here: https://github.com/sauravyash/OutFlux

It fails on the `npm test` stage of the build with:

```
> outflux@1.0.0 test /home/ubuntu/OutFlux
> electron .

Xlib:  extension "RANDR" missing on display ":99".
Xlib:  extension "RANDR" missing on display ":99".

command ((npm :test)) took more than 10 minutes since last output
```

I'm new to the whole idea of CI so bear with me if the answer is obvious.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone sees this, you must understand that running electron by itself isnt testing anything, which is the point of CI. You should use something like Spectron to test if your app is successful in headless testing (testing without a real display).

https://github.com/electron/spectron